# I have lost one complete directory from my local branch while merging in master. How to get back those lost files?

Tags: git

I was trying to update my local branch with master branch updates and lost my local folder in the process.

Comment: If the files were tracked, you can still retrieve them by checking out the local branch again. If the files were not tracked, or you had uncommitted changes to tracked files, they are gone, unless you have a backup or your filesystem provides some sort of "look-back" for previous state.

Comment: @chepner Although untracked files should not disappear through git operations (other than `git clean`, and then only with `-d` for a directory). So either they were tracked (and hence can be restored) or something else must have happened as well.

Comment: I didn't do git clean. I tried to merge the local branch with master.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `git reflog` command to find all changes to the repository even across different branches and branch transitions. Poke around in the reflog and you should be able to find what you're looking for.

Comment: I did that and tried to create one more branch with another name. But  i am getting these errors.
"Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting" with some file names.

Comment: `git reset --hard` but be warned, this will lose any uncommitted changes